# Using mongoDB for my price tracking site

Tags: mongodb

I am working on a service which tracks millions of products for price changes and needs to be able to let the users view price history, biggest discounts , prices change a few times per week sometimes per day.

right now I have

products table

- id
- category_id
- name
- photo
- sku
- supplier_id
- link
- discount (difference from last price to current price)

prices table

- product id
- timestamp
- price

I need to be able to query for:
biggest discounts
biggest discounts per category
biggest discounts per supplier
history of price for one product

is mongoDB a good fit ? can anyone give a quick start on how to convert my tables to fit the app ?

Comment: What benefits are you looking to get from MongoDB? If your current database is working fine then I don't think it's worth trying to move.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB is good for statistics processing or sth like that, it allows you to store and process data on a cluster of machines, for such simple requests you specify SQL would do.

Answer (score 0):

Like James suggested, it may be worth your while looking into what your use case is. If you are looking to scale out because you envision your DB getting slower in the future with more and more records being added to it, Mongo may be a good choice.

Mongo, is great for fast writes and quick reads but does not support the the [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) properties of a relational database. You may need a completely different structure for your Mongo collections (tables in the SQL world).

I'd suggest that you do some reading before you go one way or the other.